# How did Stamets know this?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery

In ST:DIS 1x10, "Despite Yourself", when Tyler sees Dr. Culber in sickbay, Stamets

> who is catatonic at the time and only briefly gains consciousness

tells Dr. Culber

> "Be careful! The enemy is here!"

Dr. Culber then examines Tyler and discovers

> that Tyler's body was surgically altered. (Tyler is a Klingon, Voq, and immediately kills Dr. Culber upon that revelation.)

How did Stamets know anything about that? His connection to the spore network gave him some knowledge via his

> mirror universe counterpart

which is, for instance, why he instinctively called Tilly "Captain" once.

But what could he possibly know about

> Voq/Tyler, given that the Voq in the mirror universe is the leader of a rebel faction and was not altered into appearing human?

Comment: We don't *know* that Stamets was referring to Tyler...he could have been referring to **Lorca**.

Comment: Stamets is tapped into the spore-network (mycelial-network). His conception of space and time isn't the same as others. Maybe he "saw" the future of what Tyler does leading to the warning he gives to Dr. Culbert.

Comment: @Paulie_D: Given that he uttered that sentence for the first time at the beginning of Tyler's crucial sickbay visit, and for the second time at the end of his second crucial sickbay visit (in the latter case, even presented in such a way that it appears directly link to what just happened), I think we can be pretty sure Stamets *was* referring to Tyler.

Comment: That's what they *want* you to think...:)

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D that it's not obvious Tyler is the enemy he's referring to. Is it not also possible that Mirror Universe Stamets was the enemy? I mean, if the message came from the spore network itself, then MU Stamets is definitely the biggest threat, since we later find out his work is literally killing the network and endangering all life everywhere (and presumably every_when_).

Comment: @delinear: Of course, Stamets *could* also be referring to L'Rell in the holding cell, or to the general Klingon threat. But Stamets said what he said in direct response to the scene. The second occurrence even has Tyler commit his act of violence, then looking over to Stamets, and the camera shifts focus to Stamets who repeats his sentence. From an editing point of view, the connection is obvious. What would be the point of the editing by deceiving the viewers like that? That we *think* Stamets calls Tyler the *enemy*, but actually Tyler is ... the *enemy*? I consider that truly far-fetched.

Comment: Well, one point would be deliberate misdirection. Allowing us to fall into the trap of believing Tyler is the only enemy worth worrying about, therefore we get blind-sided by the Lorca reveal and/or the MU Stamets reveal. Alternatively, so we'll continue to believe Tyler is the real enemy only to have him somehow save the day in a later episode. Both common TV/movie tricks that employ this kind of edit.

Comment: @delinear: I still consider it far-fetched. Stamets doesn't insist there's only *one* enemy (and in a war situation, "the enemy" often denotes the entire enemy faction, anyway - "the Klingons are here", for instance, would indicate that at least one of their operatives is around, *not* that *all of them* are physically present). And with Tyler attempting to murder Burnahm in the next episode, he *is* a real enemy for all intents and purposes at that point, even if he might be granted a heroic tv-redemption later on.

Comment: I'm with @delinear. In 1x12 "Vaulting Ambition", Prime Stamets utters "The enemy is here" again, whilst trapped in the mycelial network - apparently in reference to MU Stamets/his corruption of the network.  There was no apparent connection to Tyler at all in that instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon returning from the Mirror Universe, the Discovery overshot their point in the space-time continuum by 9 months. Apparently, the Mycelial Network allows for time travel as well as the regular kind.

This means it's possible that Stamets glimpsed the knowledge about Tyler/Voq from the mycelial network while catatonic/lost inside the network due to some sort of time displacement.

Comment: That does actually sound somewhat reasonable (within the confines of that series). I'll wait a bit before accepting this answer, just in case something more definitive happens to turn up.

Comment: True. According to http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Mycelial_network: `Since coordinates involve travelling through spacetime, **the mycelial network allowed travelling to specific points in time in addition to space**`

Comment: @Shreedhar Holy cow, I spelled 'Mycelial' correctly!